# Sum top three totals and group result by

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my problem...

table looks like this:

```
|id    |coutry    |sum
|  0   |  USA     |  30     
|  1   |  USA     |  60     
|  2   |  USA     |  90     
|  3   |  USA     |  80     
|  4   |  GER     |  40     
|  5   |  GER     |  90     
|  6   |  SWE     |  30     
|  7   |  SWE     |  10     
|  8   |  SWE     |  90     
|  9   |  SWE     |  40
```

and result (top three scores if exists) should be like this:

```
|coutry    |total 
|  USA     |  230 
|  GER     |  130 
|  SWE     |  160
```

Any change to solve this by sql only? I'll fetch final result using php foreach..

Comment: What did you try to make this work? Search for 'sql sum' and you will find...

Comment: @andy This is more complicated than you think.

Comment: Indeed! I didn't notice the problem is to select the top three scores *of each country* but thought that the top three countries are requested.

Answer (score 2):

The `limit` keyword should do the trick:

```
SELECT   country, SUM(`sum`)
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT    3
```

Comment: I don't think this returns the correct results. This will limit the results returned to 3, not limit the 3 top sums.

Answer (score 2):

You need to establish a row number to get the top 3 sums per country. To do this with `MySql`, you have to use user-defined variables.

```
SELECT country, SUM(`sum`)
FROM (
    SELECT *, 
        @rn:=IF(@prevCountry=country,@rn+1,1) rn,
        @prevCountry:=country
    FROM yourtable, (SELECT @rn:=0, @prevCountry:='') t
    ORDER BY country, `sum` DESC
  ) t
WHERE rn <= 3
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY country
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f6180/4)

Comment: You don't actually need the initialisation `CROSS JOIN`; the `IF` handles the `NULL` values appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Try it here because @Mureinik have right.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f6180/11)

Order by country DESC solve "TOP" problem.

Comment: please mark the right answered question

Comment: Sorry, sgeddes got it right.